# In objective-c, app crash when a responder is not found but does not crash when a message is sent to nil object. Why is that?

Tags: ios, objective-c, null

Thank you for entraining this question. I am comfortable with the idea of NULL pointer exceptions.

Now working with Objective-C I have gotten comfortable with the idea that you can send a message to a nil and nothing bad happens (it's been drilled into my head).

The question is why does an app crash when it cannot find a selector, but does not crash when sending a message to nil?

I've seen this most recently when trying to registering for NSNotification and failing to implement the method.

I am curious as to why the above is the case (or not and maybe I am really not understanding). Extra points if you can tell me how it might differ with Swift.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the difference here lies in what you are trying to call the method on.

when sending a nil object a message, nil can respond to any message sent to it always returning nil as far as i know, so nil is able to handle any method calls to it. (maybe in the underlying structure of obejctive-c, before it tries to run the selector on nil, it just instead returns nil, so it doesnt crash because it doesnt need to find the selector ever... im just theorizing here, but maybe its a good way to look at it)

when an object cannot find a selector, here you are trying to send an object (that is not nil) a message to run a selector that it doesn't have and therefore doesn't know how to handle the situation and just crashes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Are you sure that you use the term responder correctly? It is a defined term in Cocoa development. Likely you want to use the term receiver.

To your Q:

There is one major difference: Whether an *object* is existing or not (aka the reference is `nil`) is decidable at run time. Additionally to have a reference to nothing is something you can expect. (Okay, Swift developers would negotiate that.)

But you always expect that the receiver's *type* fits to your message. Even typing is dynamic in Objective-C sending a message you would expect that the receiver accepts (knows) that message. And even typing cannot be decided at compile time, in most cases the compiler can assume the expected type. So he warns you about that.

You only get to that trap, if you explicitly use the dynamic capabilities of Objective-C. (Notfications, undo management, generic containers, …)